# Image (wrapfigure) put at end of text with classicthesis for Lyx

Tags: positioning, wrapfigure, classicthesis

I often use `classicthesis`. However, now I'm facing with a problem I haven't seen before. Whenever I include a `wrapfigure`, the image appears without wrap at the end of the text block. This is the code that LyX creates:

```tex
\clearpage{}

\begin{addmargin}[-11mm]{-31mm}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\columnwidth}%
\includegraphics{../test}
\end{wrapfigure}%

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\end{addmargin}
```

This is a screenshot of the PDF that is created:
[image]

The function works great with a common article (standard class). Therefore, I assume that this is due to the `addmargin`. If so, how could I avoid that misbehavior and yet use the `addmargin` in here. Or: How to solve this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{addmargin}[-11mm]{-31mm}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\columnwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=.25\columnwidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}%

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a test file, note that you get the warnings `Package wrapfig Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment on input line 8.`   and `Package wrapfig Warning: Stationary wrapfigure forced to float on input line 12.`  so  it simply isn't supported to use `addmargin` here (which is a one item list internally)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ok - thx. But as mentioned above, I use classicthesis for Lyx. There the wrapfig package is already included and I don't get any error messages when executing ... funny.

Comment: It is not an error, but a warning, I assume classicthesis is defining addmargin in essentially the same way (as you didn't provide a testable example) but in general wrapfig doesn't work inside lists or display enviornments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ah, ok. Understand. Thx for clarification!

Comment: BTW, wrapfig has a built in overhang option that acts sort of like addmargin, at least on one side.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses negative `\hspace` and a `minipage` instead of `\addmargin`.  It won't break across pages, but it doesn't confuse so many packages either.

BTW, I assume the -31mm was a typo as it extends off the page.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}

\noindent\hspace{-11mm}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth+22mm}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\columnwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=.25\columnwidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}%

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\end{minipage}\hspace{-11mm}

\end{document}
```